# How to get unitaries, statevectors, density matrices, and everything else from the new module AerSimulator?

Tags: qiskit

So the documentation is all mixed up and I can't find how to get unitaries, statevectors, etc. in the `AerSimulator` module. For an example, see e.g. [this docs](https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/tutorials/1_aer_provider.html). In the old days, one would get this information using only the `Aer` module (as described in the previous link). But now, fresh qiskit installations do not recognize the `Aer` module and instead one has to use the "`AerSimulator`" module. If my circuit is

```
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(1, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)
circuit.h(0)
```

I call the "backend" as (not sure if correctly)

```
backend = AerSimulator(method='unitary')
```

and run

```
job = backend.run(circuit).result()
```

The `job` object has the attribute (?) `job.get_unitary()`, but I can't get the unitary matrix from it. Any idea how to extract this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add one of the [save instructions](https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/apidocs/aer_library.html#id1) to your circuit. For example, to get the unitary, add [`SaveUnitary`](https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.library.SaveUnitary.html) instruction as follows:

```
circuit.save_unitary()
```

Then, run the simulator:

```
backend = AerSimulator(method='unitary')
job = backend.run(circuit)
```

Now, you can get the unitary:

```
unitary = job.result().get_unitary()
```

Similarly, you can get the statevector by calling `circuit.save_statevector` and density matrix by calling `circuit.save_density_matrix`, ...etc.

You can also use [`SaveState`](https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.library.SaveState.html) instruction which will automatically select the format based on the simulation method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Qiskit 1.0 release notes https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/release-notes/1.0#providers-upgrade-notes the preferred method of getting your desired information is to use `qiskit.quantum_info`. For example:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator, Statevector, DensityMatrix

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.h(0)

print(Operator(qc)) # unitary
print(Statevector(qc))
print(DensityMatrix(qc))
```

```
Operator([[ 0.70710678+0.j,  0.70710678+0.j],
          [ 0.70710678+0.j, -0.70710678+0.j]],
         input_dims=(2,), output_dims=(2,))
Statevector([0.70710678+0.j, 0.70710678+0.j],
            dims=(2,))
DensityMatrix([[0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j],
               [0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j]],
              dims=(2,))
```

It is also worth noting that you can still use `Aer` as in the old days with `from qiskit_aer import Aer`.

Comment: The release notes are about migration from `BasicAer` to `quantum_info`. Both are written in Python. Aer is written in C++ and is therefore much faster. The question was about Aer, so it remains unanswered.